# Zeppelin\jupyter Notebook for KUDU

Tags: apache-kudu

We are trying to connect Zeppelin Notebook to KUDU via impala.

We didn't find any existing KUDU interpreters in addition we tried to find impala interpreters.

Any help would be appreciated

Rony